# Root route displaying blank page while other route works laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web, deployment, digital-ocean

When i load my application on the root route / it works normally on both local and on testing server. but when i deployed to production. the root route / does not work. But other route seems to work normally. for example, if i open google.com it just displays a blank page but when i open google.com/another it works fine. The application is hosted on digital ocean. What can be the possible cause?

I tried redeploying to see it the was an issue with the deployment, still nothing. I checked the htaccess file, everything looks fine.

Comment: Please show the related code

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by related code, 
At first i thought it was the method that was having the issue. so i changed the route from '/' to '/home' it works. you can see for yourself. visit www.jollof.com {This shows a blank page} but when you visit www/jollof.com/fashion {This show the coming soon page}

Comment: Can you show the code of your route for `/`? Ex. `Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome'); });`

Comment: This is what i have there

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('index');